# What is wrong with this mysqli query?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am adding a new email address to a database. 
When I check to see if the user exists using

```
if (!($stmt = $dbConnection->prepare('SELECT `email_addr` FROM '.TABLE_NAME.' WHERE `email_addr` = ?')))`
```

everything works OK.

When I attempt to run

```
if (!($stmt = $dbConnection->prepare('INSERT INTO '.TABLE_NAME.'(`email_addr`,`date_subscribed`,`act_code`,`subscribe_ip`) VALUES (?,?,?,?)' )))
```

I get the error `Unknown column 'email_addr' in 'field list'`. I have searched around a lot and thought that maybe adding the backticks would solve the problem, but it did not. If you need more code, please let me know.

SOLVED: The constant had a typo in it. Thank you to everyone for telling me to run the query in PHPmyadmin, that led me to discover the problem.

Comment: Can you post the table schema?

Comment: Are you 100% sure that `email_addr` is a field in the table?

Comment: Yes, I've used it further up in the same php script

Comment: There is not enough code to observe a problem if the column is valid. Also post the code that demonstrates its usage elsewhere.

Comment: WPINSTALL_TABLE_NAME vs TABLE_NAME ?

Comment: I was trying to make it more generic. Both are WPINSTALL in the actual script. I'll edit that.

Comment: just to test i would hard code the actual table name to see what happens.

Comment: Echo that query on the web page and then copy and paste that SQL into your phpmyadmin to see what happens.

Comment: Echo to page is `INSERT INTO the_table_name (`email_addr`,`date_subscribed`,`act_code`,`subscribe_ip`) VALUES (?,?,?,?)`

Comment: @Dagon that's just the SO markdown playing silly buggers. If you decode the markdown, the output is right.

Comment: dam my brilliance, foiled :-)

Comment: @fdsa I'm wondering if a character from an odd charset or a zero-width non-printable character has leaked into your code somewhere. I know it sounds odd, but try rewriting the line by hand (*not* copy/pasting any part of it from anywhere) and see what happens. It's a long shot but you never know.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with mysqli error reporting, but if you can `select` and not `insert`, it could be a permission problem. Perhaps the user you are using does not have permission to alter that table / column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Unknown column 'email_addr' in 'field list'
```

This error indicates that you are referencing a column name that does not exist.  Review your table to ensure that is the proper column name and ensure that you are using the correct variable in your query.

Try removing the '`' from the columns you're trying to insert into:

```
(email_addr, date_subscribed, act_code, subscribe_ip)
```

In addition, try to echo the query and run it directly in phpMyAdmin to see the result.  There may be an issue with your formatting that you are not aware of.

Comment: Yes thank you, however this column does exist and it is successfully used in another query further up the script.

Comment: @fdsa Please post additional code then as the snippet does not allow for any insight into your issue.

Comment: Try removing the '`' from the columns you're trying to insert into:

(email_addr, date_subscribed, act_code, subscribe_ip)

Comment: Still seems like a formatting issue.  Try outputting the query and executing it manually.

Answer (score 1):

write

```
echo 'SELECT `email_addr` FROM '.WPINSTALL_TABLE_NAME.' WHERE `email_addr` = ?'
```

and then to see your SQL Code qnd then try your SQL code directly in your PHPMyAdmin console and tell us what is the answer...

Comment: see latest comment on question

Answer (score 0):

maybe add space here

```
[space](`email_addr`...)
```